# Contact form Ajax, php, Jquery:

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xmlhttprequest, ajaxform

I'm trying to make a contact form with Ajax, php and Jquery for my last study project (php with mvc architecture). I have some questions about it:

- my contact form is ok: I receive emails! But I am not sure that is really an Ajax request even if I use the `$.ajax()` because in my terminal there is no XHR request...
- I would like to show a message when email is send like "Thanks for your message" but the message appear only for one second and the page is refreished so all informations are cleaned. I tryed with a `e.preventDefault()` but when I use it, I don't receive the email.

Thanks for your answers and you help.

**contat view:**

```
<section class="form_container">
        <form class="contact_form" id="contact_form" method="post" action="index.php?action=contact"> 
            <input class="firstname form" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Nom" id="firstname" required>
            <span class="error-message"></span><br/>
            <input class="lastname form" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Prénom" id="lastname" required>
            <span class="error-message"></span><br/>
            <input class="email form" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" required>
            <span class="error-message"></span><br/>
            <input class="object form" type="text" name="object" placeholder="Objet" id="object" required>
            <span class="error-message"></span><br/>
            <textarea class="content form" name="content" placeholder="Votre message" id="content" cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea>
            <span class="error-message"></span><br/>
            <input class="envoyer form" type="submit" name="submit" value="Envoyer" id="submit"><br/>
        </form>
        <div id="msg-ok">Merci. Votre message a bien été envoyé.</div>
        <div id="msg-notok">Merci de renseigner correctement tous les champs .</div>

    </section>
```

**contact_form.js:**

```
// send messages with Ajax
    'use strict';
    $('#contact_form').submit(function() {

        nom = $(this).find("#firstname").val();
        prenom = $(this).find("#lastname").val();
        email = $(this).find("#email").val();
        object = $(this).find("#object").val();
        message = $(this).find("#content").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { 
                nom:nom, 
                prenom:prenom, 
                email:email, 
                object:object, 
                content:content 
            },
            url: 'http://www.projet-5.pauline-superweb.com/index.php?action=contact',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#contact_form").hide();
                $('#msg-ok').fadeIn();  
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#msg-notok').fadeIn();
            }
        })
    });
});
```

**php code in  my controller:**

```
function contact()
{
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $e = array();
        $e['error'] = "Formulaire non valide";

        if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['object']) && isset($_POST['content']) && !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $e['email_invalide'] = "email_invalide";
        } else {
            $e['error'] = 'Ok';
            $nom = $_POST['firstname'];
            $prenom = $_POST['lastname'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $object = $_POST['object'];
            $content = $_POST['content'];

            $to = 'contact.super.web@gmail.com';
            $sujet = $object;
            $message = $content;
            $headers = 'From ' . $nom . ' ' . $prenom . ' ' . $email;
            mail($to, $sujet, $message, $headers);
        } 
    } 

    ob_start();
    include('views/frontend/site/contactView.php');
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    require("views/frontend/site/template.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
<input class="envoyer form" type="submit" name="submit" value="Envoyer" id="submit">
```

to

```
<input class="envoyer form" type="button" name="submit" value="Envoyer" id="submit">
```

and  change

```
$('#contact_form').submit(function() {
to 
$('#submit').click(function() {
```